# CSS background-image using background-position has a glitchy effect

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

The code that is having the problem is:

```
/* footer */
#footerwrapper {
    height: 225px;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url('../images/footbgRight.jpg');
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The image shows a weird bar along the bottom, for no reason I can understand. If I position it as just "right", it shows the same bar on the top AND bottom of the image.

Can anyone help me understand why the bar is showing, and what to do about it?

Comment: what browser? looks fine in opera.

Comment: I am looking at it in Chrome. The bars are not in the image. The image is located here, and you can see it has no bars:
http://www.birnamwoodgames.com/images/footer/footbgRight.jpg

Comment: @MattBrand this is the image you're using http://birnamwoodgames.com/images/footbgRight.jpg, not http://www.birnamwoodgames.com/images/footer/footbgRight.jpg

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the bar that I am seeing. I see it in both Firefox and Chrome:

http://www.birnamwoodgames.com/bwgError.jpg

Comment: When I open your image (http://birnamwoodgames.com/images/footbgRight.jpg) in Photoshop I see the bands. It's in the image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add a little more information about your specific case to this page? Questions that depend on a link to an external website are discouraged for the reasons outlined in [this FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Ah, I see it. The problem was in the image itself, and I uploaded it as a different file (as given by an artist), but did not change the name in the page. Thanks so much!

Comment: @LordTorgamus - sorry about the external link. Will not happen again.

Comment: No problem, glad you got your problem sorted out. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

You specified the background not to repeat. Since the background image doesn't repeat and is shorter than the height you specified, the browser will render the rest of the background as your background color, which is black. That is the bar you are seeing.

EDIT: I see it now. @Musa's comment from earlier is correct. It appears to be in the image itself and is not a CSS thing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The bar I am seeing is not black.

Comment: I am going to take a screenshot and post what I am seeing. It shows the weird bar in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the bar that I am seeing:

http://www.birnamwoodgames.com/bwgError.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is inheriting the background color from `#headborder {}` declared in styleNew.css on line 15

You can try adding `background:none;` to the beginning of `#footerwrapper` but that is not likely to solve the problem, you will have to either repeat the background in `#footerwrapper`  or kill the background color in `#headborder`, you could also try adding a `background-color:white;` to `#footerwrapper`